# element.width is returing undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep trying to log element.width and it returns `undefined`

```
<div width="24" id="element"></div>
<script>
    console.log( document.getElementById( 'element' ).width );
</script>
```

I want to get the attribute not clientWidth or offsetWidth or anything else.

Comment: `width` is not a valid attribute of a `div` element. You’ll need to use DOM methods like `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

For get the element `width` attribute, you could use the method `getAttribute("width")`, you can read about it on: [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). Or alternatively access the propery `attributes.width.value` (read [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)). Example:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('element').getAttribute("width"))
console.log(document.getElementById('element').attributes.width.value)
```

```html
<div width="24" id="element"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome, please, take into consideration check the answer as correct if don't bother you.